# E: Unable to locate package libcr-dev

Tags: 20.04, libraries, locate, mpi

I am trying to run a script (astrophysics stuff) using mpirun. I executed the command:

```
mpirun -n 3 ./harm
```

and got this error:

```
/usr/local/bin/hydra_pmi_proxy: error while loading shared libraries: libcr.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[mpiexec@sajal-Aspire-E5-574] HYD_pmcd_pmiserv_proxy_init_cb (pm/pmiserv/pmiserv_cb.c:448): assert (!closed) failed
[mpiexec@sajal-Aspire-E5-574] HYDT_dmxu_poll_wait_for_event (tools/demux/demux_poll.c:77): callback returned error status
[mpiexec@sajal-Aspire-E5-574] HYD_pmci_wait_for_completion (pm/pmiserv/pmiserv_pmci.c:196): error waiting for event
[mpiexec@sajal-Aspire-E5-574] main (ui/mpich/mpiexec.c:336): process manager error waiting for completion
```

Note: harm is the name of the executable script. I did some googling and found that if I install the library called: libcr-dev, the above error (regarding the problem of locating libcr.so.0) might get solve. However, when I try to install it using:

```
sudo apt-get install libcr-dev
```

I got the error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libcr-dev
```

I try to find the solution to the above problem but I failed. I am using ubuntu 20.04. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `libcr` package was last available [on 18.04 LTS](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/blcr). To install it on 20.04 LTS you have to download and install it manually:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/b/blcr/libcr0_0.8.5-2.3_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/b/blcr/libcr-dev_0.8.5-2.3_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install ./libcr0_0.8.5-2.3_amd64.deb ./libcr-dev_0.8.5-2.3_amd64.deb
```

---

Also I should note that `hydra_pmi_proxy` [is provided](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=hydra_pmi_proxy%60) by official `mpich` package. You can use it instead of locally compiled version. This will prevent problems with library and package dependencies.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. After following your steps, I got the error that dependencies are broken. So, I fixed it using apt --fix-broken. Now, its working.

Also, as I am curious about hydra_pmi_proxy, I clicked on your hyperlink but I think its broken. Could you edit it?
Thanks again!